# IText 5.5.3. 508 Compliance with JAWS 16

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I am having issues printing 508 compliant Tagged PDF files that has Tables in them. For some reason, JAWS doesn't read the accessibility text for a PdfPTable.

In the below code snippet, JAWS reads the ALT text for the Chunk but it doesn't read for the PdfPCell and PdfPTable.  Please Help!

```
    /**
 * Creates a PDF with information about the movies
 * @param    filename the name of the PDF file that will be created.
 * @throws    DocumentException 
 * @throws    IOException
 */
public void createPdf(String filename)
    throws IOException, DocumentException {
    // step 1
    Document document = new Document();
    // step 2
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
    writer.setPdfVersion(PdfWriter.VERSION_1_7);
    writer.setTagged();
    writer.setViewerPreferences(PdfWriter.DisplayDocTitle);
    document.addLanguage("en-US");
    document.addTitle("Some title");
    writer.createXmpMetadata();
    // step 3
    document.open();
    // step 4
    Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph();
    p1.setFont(FontFactory.getFont(
            FONT, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 20));
    Chunk c1 = new Chunk("What is this?");
    c1.setAccessibleAttribute(PdfName.ALT, new PdfString(" Q1. What is this?"));

    p1.add(c1);
    document.add(p1);
    document.add(createFirstTable());
    // step 5
    document.close();
}

/**
 * Creates our first table
 * @return our first table
 */
public static PdfPTable createFirstTable() {
    // a table with three columns
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
    table.setAccessibleAttribute(PdfName.ALT, new PdfString("My Table"));
    // the cell object
    PdfPCell cell;
    // we add a cell with colspan 3
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell with colspan 3"));
    cell.setAccessibleAttribute(PdfName.TD, new PdfString("Cell 1"));
    cell.setColspan(3);
    table.addCell(cell);
    // now we add a cell with rowspan 2
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell with rowspan 2"));
            cell.setRowspan(2);
    table.addCell(cell);
    // we add the four remaining cells with addCell()
    table.addCell("row 1; caa*");
    table.addCell("row 1; c+");
    table.addCell("row 2; c-");
    table.addCell("row 2; c/");
    return table;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with iText 5.5.10? PDF/UA was high on the roadmap in the 5.5.x series and in iText 7.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie: Thanks for your prompt response. I bumped the version to 5.5.10 like you suggested. Its the same result, Jaws doesnt read the alternate text for the table.

Comment: In that case, I can't help you. iText 7 has a higher priority for us than iText 5. Do you have a support contract? If so, you should post a ticket on JIRA.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I dont have a support contract. I have one question though, does iText 7 have better support for accessibility. I know i have re-write most of my code, but it could be worth it if it doesnt have the same issues as iText 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow! 508 can be really frustrating. After a couple of days, i was able to figure out a way out. I stumbled on the method: [createTaggedPDF17()](https://sourceforge.net/p/itext/itextpdf/ci/c7a82e08843f306d913e03ad9259a0016528f858/tree/itext/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/TaggedPDFTest.java?diff=3afda4de6bc2a5207245589082f01f8396227684). I created a PdfPHeaderSet for the first row and added an header for each of the cells in the table body.

It worked perfectly! JAWS read the alternate text just the way i wanted it.

I dont know why it didnt work before. But this solved my problem.

```
public static PdfPTable createFirstTable() {
    // a table with three columns
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);

    // the cell object
    PdfPCell cell;
    // we add a cell with colspan 3
    //create header cell for first row
    PdfPHeaderCell headerCell = new PdfPHeaderCell();
    headerCell.setScope(PdfPHeaderCell.ROW);
    headerCell.setPhrase(new Phrase("Cell with colspan 3"));
    headerCell.setName("header Cell");
    headerCell.setAccessibleAttribute(PdfName.TD, new PdfString("Cell 1"));
    headerCell.setColspan(3);
    table.addCell(headerCell);
    // now we add a cell with rowspan 2
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell with rowspan 2"));

    //add metadata for each cell in the body.
    cell.addHeader(headerCell);

    cell.setRowspan(2);
    table.addCell(cell);
    // we add the four remaining cells with addCell()
    table.addCell("row 1; caa*");
    table.addCell("row 1; c+");
    table.addCell("row 2; c-");
    table.addCell("row 2; c/");

    //set header row for the table
    table.setHeaderRows(1);

    return table;
}
```